# Perl: Module with group_by function to convert array of hashrefs to hash of arrayrefs

Tags: perl

Given an array of hashrefs:

```
my @items = (
    {
        key   => 'a-key',
        value => 'a-value-1',
    },
    {
        key   => 'a-key',
        value => 'a-value-2',
    },
    {
        key   => 'b-key',
        value => 'b-value-1',
    },
    {
        key   => 'b-key',
        value => 'b-value-2',
    },
);
```

I want to produce a hash with the values stored in arrayrefs grouped by keys:

```
my %grouped = (
    'a-key' => ['a-value-1', 'a-value-2'],
    'b-key' => ['b-value-1', 'b-value-2'],
);
```

I know this can be done natively by just looping over the elements:

```
my %grouped;
for my $item (@items) {
    push @{ $grouped{$item->{key}} }, $item->{value};
}
```

But it seems like a common enough formula for there to be a module that provides a function similar to [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) or [Underscore JS](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)'s group by functions. Is there a commonly used library in Perl that provides a similar function?

In anticipation of someone mentioning `List::Util::reduce`, that doesn't seem any less complex than the native way to me, and it's seems awkward to use it to produce a hashref.

```
my $grouped = reduce {
    push @{ $a->{$b->{key}} }, $b->{value};
    $a;
} {}, @items;
```

I'm imagining a usage like this:

```
my %grouped = group_by { $_->{key} } @items;
```

Edit: I've just realised that if we use `group_by` above, we still need to process the result further, something like this:

```
for my $arrayref (values %grouped) {
    $_ = $_->{value} for @$arrayref;
}
```

Comment: The choices are a single line of code using well known syntax vs learning a new api in a new module. IMHO, the strength of perl is to have a syntax so smart that modules are not needed for mundane tasks.

Comment: @BOC well it is 4 lines, not one line. ;-) I'm assuming you mean you prefer the `for` method over `reduce`? It was actually a difference of opinion with a colleague between `for` and `reduce` that caused me to post this question. I thought `group_by` would be a nice compromise, but since realising it's not any simpler, I'm back to preferring the simple loop.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip  With the above comment, I'd rush to say that I strongly prefer the loop over `reduce`. (I am not aware of a module with such specific functionality.)  You can also write the loop in one line if that matters (`push ...  for @items`), + declaration.  Or put it in a sub, which may grow into a small utility module if more comes along. (Even the same interface `group_by { } LIST` can be set up.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a library function for this, so I wrote one myself.

```
sub group_by (&@) {
    my ($get_kv, @items) = @_;

    my %groups;
    for (@items) {
        my ($k, $v) = ($get_kv->(), $_);
        push @{ $groups{$k} }, $v;
    }
    %groups;
}
```

Inside the block, the first element specifies the key to group by, and the second element optionally specifies the value that will be grouped. If no second element is provided, the entire item is used as the value.

Usage:

```
my %keys_to_values = group_by { $_->{key}, $_->{value} } @items;
# (
#     'a-key' => [qw(a-value-1 a-value-2)],
#     'b-key' => [qw(b-value-1 b-value-2)],
# )

my %keys_to_items = group_by { $_->{key} } @items;
# (
#    'a-key' => [
#        {
#            key   => 'a-key',
#            value => 'a-value-1',
#        },
#        {
#            key   => 'a-key',
#            value => 'a-value-2',
#        },
#    ],
#    'b-key' => [
#        {
#            key   => 'b-key',
#            value => 'b-value-1',
#        },
#        {
#            key   => 'b-key',
#            value => 'b-value-2',
#        },
#    ],
# )
```

Comment: Nice. In "_The block can return an optional second value_" do you mean to say that it can "take" an optional second value (instead of "_return_")?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your perspective. From the caller's perspective, maybe "take" is a better word choice. From the execution perspective, the block is a subroutine that we call in list context, using one or two elements of the returned list. How about "If a list is provided to the block, the first element specifies the key to group by, and the second element specifies the value that will be grouped. If no second element is provided, the entire item is used as the value."

Comment: Sure, a good point (but people generally consider interfaces from the user's perspective).  Since it can mislead on a casual read more of an explanation may indeed be a good idea, and what you give is precise and completely clear.  A nice thing about this interface (with a code block) is that you can later easily tweak and expand functionality, if a need arises (I presume it won't be getting shipped).  Not to mention that it is a nice "starter" for a module if you need more of some similar custom processing.

Comment: Updated the description. Thanks for your feedback.